# Attempting to store references to c++ vectors returned by reference still giving me copies

Tags: c++11, multidimensional-array, vector, reference, return-type

Back in '98 I converted my chemical model from objective-c to c++ after replacing my old NeXT, but I didn't really get a chance to *learn* c++.  I'm now rewriting the code into modern c++, which means learning to use containers, smart pointers, and templates.

I need to parse output variables only once up front, rather than at each time step, so I originally produced a pointer array of output variable pointers (`float ***outVars`).  I could run through the list of pointers after each time interval, and since `outVars` pointed to the original data, they would always provide the current state of the model.

I'm changing code from matrices of naked pointers to matrices of vectors.  I haven't been able to return anything but copies of vectors, rather than references to the original vectors.  I don't want to modify the vectors, I just need direct read access.

I can't believe I haven't found my answer online yet.  Most that I've found online has simply said use `std::vector<float> &` to return by reference, but clearly that isn't working.

I saw one note that assigning a reference to a non-reference value (I assume they meant variable) will make it copy, so I tried `fvec2D &outVar2D;` (see the header file below).

I've tried with and without const, no difference.

I've tried returning `vector.data()`, but assigning it to a new vector was also copying.  Maintaining pointers to `.data()` memory blocks seems be a very bad idea, if I need to resize the original vector.

I've tried wrapping the vector in `std::shared_ptr`, but found I'd need to wrap each dimension vector in a shared_ptr, which got overly cumbersome real fast.

I saw one suggestion to return `vector::iterator`s.  I haven't managed to get that to work yet.  Maybe having 2D data is getting in the way of that.  I'm still trying to get that to run without crashing when I examine the iterator.

I don't know if using a 1D array would solve this, but calculating every index reference for millions of calls seems suboptimal.
 I considered using `std::array` too but vectors seemed the simplest conversion.  Perhaps I should rethink that.

If anyone has any suggestions for how to do this, I'd very much appreciate it.

class chem - manages original matrix `concentration`

```
    class chem
    {
     public:
        typedef std::vector<float> fvec1D;
        typedef std::vector<std::vector<float> > fvec2D;

        chem(int xstep, int zstep) : concentration(xstep, fvec1D(zstep, 1.5)) {}

        ...

        const fvec2D &getConc() const { return concentration; }
        const fvec1D &getConc(int x) const {return concentration[x]; }

    private:
        fvec2D      concentration;
    };
```

class model - needs read access to `chem::concentration`

```
    class model
    {
    public:
        typedef std::vector<float> fvec1D;
        typedef std::vector<std::vector<float> > fvec2D;

    ...

    private:

        fvec2D      null2D {{0.0}};
        fvec1D      null1D {0.0};

        fvec2D      &outVar2D;// = null2D; // tried this and at ctor
        fvec1D      &outVar1D;// = null1D;


        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<chem> > chemList;
    };

    model::model() : outVar2D(null2D), outVar1D(null1D)
    {
        outVar2D = chemList[0]->getConc();      // or
        outVar1D = chemList[0]->getConc(1);
    }

    void model::plot()
    {
        for (int z=0; z<numZSteps; ++z) {
            std::cout << outVar1D[z];
            std::cout << outVar2D[1][z];
        }
    }

    void model::run()
    {
        plot();             // produces init concentration of 1.5 at each z

        chemList[0]->changeConc(); // Changes values in concentration

        plot();             // STILL produces init conc of 1.5 at each z
    }
```

Comment: TMI. Reduce your code to a no more than a dozen lines that demonstrate your undesired behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Sam.  Let me know if I went too far / not far enough.

Comment: This is either fake code and not real code, or you're using a broken C++ compiler. No self-respecting C++ compiler will compile it, as shown. When a class has a member that are references, they must be initialized in the constructor. `model::model()` fails to initialize its two reference members. Assignment in the body of a constructor is not initialization (and this will end up corrupting memory, by assigning an uninitialized reference, resulting in random crashes). There's your copy.

Comment: Awesome!  The original code was running fine in Qt (gcc 5.4.0) without even a warning.  More to learn!  Thanks @Sam!!!

Comment: @Sam I did a make clean and got my compiler complaints - had to make clean pretty much after every edit - which is unusual.  Unfortunately the result is the same.  I'm still getting copies.  Ah, well.  Premature celebration.  I edited the code above to show the initializations.  Compiles/runs without warnings, and the debugger shows the init is as expected.

Comment: Of course you're getting copies. What do you think the assignments, in the constructor, do? You're signing from X to Y. Just because Y is a reference, that doesn't magically make the copy go away.

Comment: @Sam I'd hoped since the get* returns a reference, and since I am storing it into a reference, I would have a reference instead of a copy.  No worries.  I'll keep going.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: A reference is not an object itself. Once a reference is created it always refers to whatever it is the reference to, and any usage of the reference ends up referring to the referenced-to object.

Comment: A reference cannot be assigned, it can only be constructed.

Comment: Thank you @n.m.  There was some conflicting terminology in what I've been reading, and that simple sentence made a lot of it suddenly very clear!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if answering my own question is appropriate (please let me know). I know this question will be autodeleted, so I thought I'd present the solution I came up with, because I'm still VERY interested in hearing any suggestions of the best way to do this.  I'm still so far down the learning curve I know I can't intuitively see c++ programming techniques.

I gathered from comments that what I was trying won't work, so I wrapped my vectors in `shared_ptr`s, which I know can work.  I created some wrapper classes to manage 2 levels of `shared_ptr` (one for the multidimensional spatial data, and one for the list of output variables).  It also keeps the array-type indexing intact as well as defines behavior for `operator=`.

I have only included the 2D classes here.  I have 4 similar classes to handle the 1D and 3D cases as well.

I know what I'm posting is not great.  it's not very elegant, requiring 2 classes for each dimensional case (1D, 2D, 3D data).  Perhaps I can simplify it using templates.  I've only written very elementary templates so far.  Since each class decays (using `operator[]`) to a unique class I'm not sure if a template will help.

I haven't figured out all the `const` keyword placements yet - I removed them all for now, out of frustration with the compiler complaints.  I'll get that down when I can take the time.

I also don't know exactly what sort of behavior I want for copy and move constructors, though I'm pretty sure I need them for vector resize operations, which I just realized I haven't even implemented yet.  The important thing for me here was just to get read access to the vectors across classes, such that when the vectors change it is reflected elsewhere without re-parsing my output variables.

```
    #include <memory>
    #include <vector>

    namespace MDType {
        class fpv2D;

        typedef std::vector<float> fvec1D;
        typedef std::vector<std::vector<float> > fvec2D;
        typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float> > > fvec3D;

        typedef std::shared_ptr<fvec1D> fvec1Dptr;
        typedef std::shared_ptr<fvec2D> fvec2Dptr;
        typedef std::shared_ptr<fvec3D> fvec3Dptr;

        typedef std::vector<fpv2D> fvpv2D;

        typedef std::shared_ptr<fvpv2D> fvpv2Dptr;

        class fpv2D
        {
        public:
            fpv2D(int x=1, int z=1, float fill=0.0) : theArray(new fvec2D(x, fvec1D(z, fill))) {}

            fpv2D(const fpv2D &otherT) = default;       //  Pretty sure this needs to change

            fpv2D( fpv2D &&otherT) {theArray = otherT.data(); }

            fvec2Dptr &data() { return theArray; }

            fvec1D &operator[](int index) {return theArray->data()[index]; }
            void operator=( fpv2D& rhs) { theArray = rhs.data(); }

        private:
            fvec2Dptr theArray;
        };

        class fpvpv2D
        {
        public:
            fpvpv2D(int index, int x=1, int z=1, float fill=0.0) : theArray(new fvpv2D(index, fpv2D(x, z, fill))) {}

            fpvpv2D(const fpvpv2D &otherT) = default;       //  Pretty sure this needs to change

            fpvpv2D( fpvpv2D &&otherT) {theArray = otherT.data(); }

            fvpv2Dptr &data() { return theArray; }

            fpv2D &operator[](int index) {return theArray->data()[index]; }
            void operator=( fpvpv2D& rhs) { theArray = rhs.data(); }

        private:
            fvpv2Dptr theArray;
        };
    }
```

... so ...

```
    MDType::fpv2D       conc(numX, numZ, 1.5);
    MDType::fpvpv2D     outVar2D(numOutVars, numX, numZ);

    outVar2D[1] = conc;
    cout << outVar2D[1][3][5];          // prints 1.5
    conc[3][5] = 12.0;
    cout << outVar2D[1][3][5];          // prints 12.0
```